# How to configure SSL connection to a Redis server with Private Key, Public Key, Authority and Password

Tags: c#, ssl, redis, stackexchange.redis

How to configure SSL connection to a Redis server with Private Key, Public Key, Authority and Password? I can successfully connect to "Another Redis Desktop" but not to StackExchange.Redis 2.66

Comment: See following : https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/TLS.md  SSL is obsolete but often term is used when using the newer version TLS.  The issue may be authentication and not TLS.